# Convert Slick 3.0 Query results into a Akka Streams GraphStage

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, slick-3.0

Is there any example available where somone queries mysql using slick3.0 and the results of the query are converted into a AkkaStream GraphStage?

I don't want to write a custom GraphStage of my own (unless absolutely necessary).

I am pretty sure that there should be some way of converting the query results into GraphStage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slick supports streaming of query results, and that is done by adhering to the [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/) API.

You can call `.stream` on a Slick database, and get back a `org.reactivestreams.Publisher`.

This can be wrapped into an Akka streams `Source` by calling `Source.fromPublisher(dbPublisher)`.

You can find more info in the [docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/dbio.html#streaming), and a complete example in [this repo](https://github.com/dnvriend/slick3-test).